# What are my option to print without any dialog box or prompt in blazor webassembly

Tags: printing, blazor-client-side, printing-web-page, blazor-webassembly

I am creating Blazor webassembly app.
I have a need to print some documents on the click of a button.
What are my options to print without any further prompts or dialog box ?
I should be able to print to variety of printers like label(barcode) as well a receipt prints.
I am ok with option to have some add-ins/plugin as last option if no native functionality can be availed.

Comment: Have you ever found any solution with blazor ? If yes,please inform us.Because i wonder too like you

Comment: Not yet. The options i will explore are using FireFox, which does allow that, or just create an desktop app which would actually print but print would be triggered from Blazor app. There is another option to use Electron to wrap Blazor and print from Electron